# How to access Flask app using Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, flask

I'm trying to run a Flask application on Amazon Linux AMI, so I do the following:

```
>>> cd /var/www/testapp
>>> python test.py
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Looks good so far, and I'm currently using localtunnel to access the site, so:

```
>>> localtunnel 5000
Port 5000 is now publicly accessible from http://xxxx.localtunnel.com ...
```

So localtunnel is doing something that makes test.py running on port 5000 publicly accessible. How do I do this on my own?

I used ifconfig and tried different combinations of the ip addresses it gave at port 5000 in my browser, but none of them worked.

EDIT: I tried attaching an elastic IP to the instance and accessing it through there but it's still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely answer, without knowing any other information, is that your security group for this instance needs to be opened for port 5000.

If that is not the case, we will need more information, logs, etc.

Comment: Hm I'm pretty sure the port is open... For its security group, it says "TCP Port (Service): 5000 Source: 0.0.0.0/0".

What logs do you need?

Comment: You are going to need a webserver to host the application. Google setting up python on nginx, or apache or something. Localtunnel does this for you behind the scenes and it looks like you are not running one.